# Hide Fields with Django and GenericViews

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django with Generic views to create my api. From the image below, I would like to hide the field status process and only show the topic field.

[image]

This is the code I'm using

```
class TopicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Topics
        fields = '__all__'

class ListCreateTopic(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.Topics.objects.order_by('-time_stamp')[:5]
    serializer_class = serializers.TopicSerializer
```

Comment: Share the serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the `status_process` in [**`readonly_fields`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields), so:

```
class TopicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Topics
        fields = '__all__'
        readonly_fields = ['status_process']
```